# IE css placement dont work as in FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress

I can't believe the number of bugs I have to sort out due to IE6...Can somebody have a solution to all the IE problem in WordPress ?

here is the file : http://www.notrepanorama.com/
you have to login to view it
http://www.notrepanorama.com/wp-login.php
login/ psw : test / test

NOW in firefox (real browser) you see the red box (top right of the photo) "nous joindre" OVER the picture and in IE6... it push DOWN the pic...

if I have no choice I will put the picture in the background of the box... but for some technical reason i prefer no to... i like to make it work as is

I know z-index and absolute positioning but i like the box to be center horizontally and relative placement is a must...i'm open to any suggestions, and i will try any solutions !

Comment: Not a solution, but it might at least cheer you up :-) : http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/time_breakdown.png

Comment: Really funny, and true indeed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having wai 2 days, and receive no answer... i put a ie6 update screen, and image on background... work fine, thanks